# Limit number of processed record by hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i have a hugh file (hive table with over 20 billions of records)
and i need to run a mapreduce that will process the first 10k number of records.

is there an effective way to limit the number of processed record by hadoop mapreduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LIMIT with task specification. However if you have to do it again and again then a better automated solution is to use OOZIE (work flow editor for hadoop) that can create partitions in hive for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [LIMIT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause):

```sql
SELECT * FROM T LIMIT 10000
```

But it returns 10k random records. As MapReduce processes data blocks independently you can't say which record is first and which is last.

Here is a trick to get what you want in case you know the order of records:

```sql
SET mapred.reduce.tasks = 1
SELECT * FROM T SORT BY SORT_FIELD DESC LIMIT 10000
```

Still you'll have to process all 20 billions of records.

Comment: so there is no way to processes only 10k recored?

Comment: that's why it's called Big Data